# Page title, description using angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have tried / used all the possible references on stackoverflow and other tutorials but could not get page title, description to work.
My state code looks like this

```
     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home/welcome');
      $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: "/home",
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: "views/home_base.html",
          controller : "HomebaseCtrl"
        })

        .state('home.welcome', {
          url: '/welcome',
          templateUrl: 'views/welcome.html',
          controller: 'WelcomeCtrl'
        })
```

In my controller 'WelcomeCtrl' file I want to set page title and description for the page. I have used rootScope but the rootScope value doesnot bind in the index.html file.

In my index.html file

```
  <html>
  <head>
   <title>{{pagetitle}}</title>
  </head>
  <div ui-view=""></div>
```

routes the home_base.html file which inturns routes welcome.html file.

Controller

```
angular.module('ragamixApp')
  .controller('WelcomeCtrl', function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.pagetitle = "Hi..I am Page Title";
   })
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: your controller? code? update that to post

Comment: You are trying to bind element that are outside of the application. If you want to have access to `{{pagetitle}}` it has to be under a controlled dom element.

Comment: Where is your controller?

Comment: I think you are missing ng-app directive.
put `ng-app="ragamixApp"` directive in you html tag.

Comment: @UmairAhmed - You killed it bro !!! Thanks

Comment: @Subhajit so no issues now??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing ng-app directive. 
put `ng-app="ragamixApp"` directive in you html tag.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Answer (score 0):

You just try this.

If you take a look at ui-router sample app, they use the angular .run block to add the $state variable to $rootScope.

```
.run([ '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
  $rootScope.$state = $state;
  $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}])
```

Setup the state the same way:

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
    data : { pageTitle: 'Home' }
})
```

Html

```
<title ng-bind="$state.current.data.pageTitle"></title>
```

Comment: I have tried that but with no luck. is there a problem with me using <div ui-view=""></div> nested ? I mean in index.html file I have used <div ui-view=""></div> to route my abstract state and then in that html file i have used again <div ui-view=""></div> to route the welcome.html contents? Also angular 1.6 is what I am using

Comment: you check this.   https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-&-nested-views